# FClick on nested item is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have this html:

```
<div class="task" id="1">
   Item1
</div>
<div class="task" id="2">
   Item2
</div>
<div class="task" id="3">
   Item3
</div>
```

And JavaScript load subitems. If i click on static item it is working. But if i click on loaded sub items, their subsubitems don`t load.

I created test page to show this: http://helloworld.dimkos.ru/

This code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.task').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    var task = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "./sub.php?sub=" + id,
        success: function(html) {
            $(task).append(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});});
```

./sub.php?sub=1
append subitems which parent have id
Click on dynamically added subitems is not working.

Solved with  $('.task').live("click", function(e)

Comment: Show a little more code than that.

Comment: It's not clear what id=1 or id=2 are. Also, which element has the `task` class is also not clear.

Comment: There is no `event` in your callback in the given example.

Comment: how is anyone supposed to understand what behavior you want without an explanation? `does not work` doesn't tell anyone what is supposed to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like this and test it again:

```
$('.task').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(id);
});​
```

See if the first & second case is working or not, [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BpRWT/) :)

Comment: Don't work, if i get sub items dynamically.

Comment: Then you need to try this [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BpRWT/1/)

Comment: I created page to demonstrate this problem.
[link]http://helloworld.dimkos.ru/
I have 3 items. if I click on Item1, ajax append Subitem4,5,6 if I click SubItem4 ajax must append Subitem7,8,9. But it is not working.

Comment: I solve problem with $('.task').live("click", function(e)

Comment: Great. Just a suggestion, go through this before using live [on-vs-live-review](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/)

Comment: Thanks, it's really useful. I used ON incorrectly, but now I know how use it.
$('body').on("click", ".task", function(e)